# android- How to insert a line between a line

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I want to insert a line between a line . this is the image of what I need :

[image]

I really don't know what should I do ?
could you help me

Comment: paste ur xml we will

Comment: use drawable left and drawable right for the textview if its is images.or draw a line programatically and convert it to darwable and apply as drawable left and right with paddings

Comment: hi Mahdi, I have posted my answer, Please refer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just giving you the sample, You can change color or drawable according to your requirement. If you have still any query, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="line_image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:text="test"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```